# SQL Server: создание Sql Script на основе DataSet

Tags: .net, sql-server

Есть DataSet с несколькими таблицами.

На основе DataTable и DataRelation из DataSet надо создать Sql Script, который позволит создать соответствующие таблицы в базе данных в SQL Server.

Какие классы в .NET можно использовать для решение такой задачи?

Метод должен на основе DataSet создать текст sql-скрипта, который можно выполнить в SQL Server, и в результате в базе данных будут созданы таблицы, соответствующие таблицам в DataSet.

> Добавьте в вопрос пример, что вы хотите подавать на вход и ожидаемый выход для указанного входа – Grundy

на вход подается DataSet, например, такой

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("mytable");
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int));
dc.AutoIncrement = true;
dc.Unique = true;
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dt.PrimaryKey = new [] { dc };
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

на выходе должен получиться sql скрипт

```
create table mytable (id int identity primary key)
```

Прошу обратить внимание, что **нужно общее решение**, а не только для этого конкретного примера.

Comment: можете привести пример данных и ожидаемого скрипта?

Comment: Мне не данные нужны, а только схема. Ожидаемый скрипт обычный: `create table [имятаблицы] ( поля таблицы )`, его нужно создать на основе DataColumn из DataTable

Comment: в данном случае данными как раз и выступают DataTable и т.д. Добавьте в вопрос пример, что вы хотите подавать на вход и ожидаемый выход для указанного входа

Comment: На вход DataSet, а на выходе - sql script.

Comment: я просил _конкретный_ пример, абзац который вы добавили, повторяет второй который уже был

Comment: Пример добавил, но обратите внимание, что нужно общее решение.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35960/discussion-between-grundy-and-box).

Comment: Если говорить об общем решении, то что должно происходить в ситуации, если будет 2 одинаковых столбца, `id1` и `id2`? Какой из них должен будет стать `primary key`?

Comment: @Yaant добавил в вопрос `dt.PrimaryKey = new [] { dc };`

Answer (score 1):

Решение взято с [enSO: Creating a SQL Server table from a C# datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27242077/1988244). Суть его - пройтись по всем колонкам таблицы и сгенерировать соответствующий SQL.

Вам нужно вызвать его для всех таблиц в DataSet.

```
/// <summary>
/// Inspects a DataTable and return a SQL string that can be used to CREATE a TABLE in SQL Server.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="table">System.Data.DataTable object to be inspected for building the SQL CREATE TABLE statement.</param>
/// <returns>String of SQL</returns>
public static string GetCreateTableSql(DataTable table)
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder alterSql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.AppendFormat("CREATE TABLE [{0}] (", table.TableName);

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        bool isNumeric = false;
        bool usesColumnDefault = true;

        sql.AppendFormat("\n\t[{0}]", table.Columns[i].ColumnName);

        switch (table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString().ToUpper())
        {
            case "SYSTEM.INT16":
                sql.Append(" smallint");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.INT32":
                sql.Append(" int");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.INT64":
                sql.Append(" bigint");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.DATETIME":
                sql.Append(" datetime");
                usesColumnDefault = false;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.STRING":
                sql.AppendFormat(" nvarchar({0})", table.Columns[i].MaxLength);
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.SINGLE":
                sql.Append(" single");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.DOUBLE":
                sql.Append(" double");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            case "SYSTEM.DECIMAL":
                sql.AppendFormat(" decimal(18, 6)");
                isNumeric = true;
                break;
            default:
                sql.AppendFormat(" nvarchar({0})", table.Columns[i].MaxLength);
                break;
        }

        if (table.Columns[i].AutoIncrement)
        {
            sql.AppendFormat(" IDENTITY({0},{1})", 
                table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementSeed, 
                table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementStep);
        }
        else
        {
            // DataColumns will add a blank DefaultValue for any AutoIncrement column. 
            // We only want to create an ALTER statement for those columns that are not set to AutoIncrement. 
            if (table.Columns[i].DefaultValue != null)
            {
                if (usesColumnDefault)
                {
                    if (isNumeric)
                    {
                        alterSql.AppendFormat("\nALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_{0}_{1}]  DEFAULT ({2}) FOR [{1}];", 
                            table.TableName, 
                            table.Columns[i].ColumnName, 
                            table.Columns[i].DefaultValue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alterSql.AppendFormat("\nALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_{0}_{1}]  DEFAULT ('{2}') FOR [{1}];", 
                            table.TableName, 
                            table.Columns[i].ColumnName, 
                            table.Columns[i].DefaultValue);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Default values on Date columns, e.g., "DateTime.Now" will not translate to SQL.
                    // This inspects the caption for a simple XML string to see if there is a SQL compliant default value, e.g., "GETDATE()".
                    try
                    {
                        System.Xml.XmlDocument xml = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

                        xml.LoadXml(table.Columns[i].Caption);

                        alterSql.AppendFormat("\nALTER TABLE {0} ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_{0}_{1}]  DEFAULT ({2}) FOR [{1}];", 
                            table.TableName, 
                            table.Columns[i].ColumnName, 
                            xml.GetElementsByTagName("defaultValue")[0].InnerText);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        // Handle
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!table.Columns[i].AllowDBNull)
        {
            sql.Append(" NOT NULL");
        }

        sql.Append(",");
    }

    if (table.PrimaryKey.Length > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder primaryKeySql = new StringBuilder();

        primaryKeySql.AppendFormat("\n\tCONSTRAINT PK_{0} PRIMARY KEY (", table.TableName);

        for (int i = 0; i < table.PrimaryKey.Length; i++)
        {
            primaryKeySql.AppendFormat("{0},", table.PrimaryKey[i].ColumnName);
        }

        primaryKeySql.Remove(primaryKeySql.Length - 1, 1);
        primaryKeySql.Append(")");

        sql.Append(primaryKeySql);
    }
    else
    {
        sql.Remove(sql.Length - 1, 1);
    }

    sql.AppendFormat("\n);\n{0}", alterSql.ToString());

    return sql.ToString();
}
```

Comment: там в соседних вопросах предлагали схему в xsd сохранить а потом сторонней программой по ней sql построить

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не генерировать скрипт самому, можно воспользоваться библиотекой [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx).

Пример из MSDN ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.create.aspx)):

```
Server srv = new Server("(local)");
Database db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2012"];

Table tb = new Table(db, "Test Table");
Column col1 = new Column(tb, "Name", DataType.NChar(50));
Column col2 = new Column(tb, "ID", DataType.Int);

tb.Columns.Add(col1);
tb.Columns.Add(col2);
```

Далее можно вызвать `tb.Script()`, чтобы получить скрипт для создания таблицы, или `tb.Create()`, чтобы сразу создать таблицу в БД.

К сожалению у класса `Smo.Table` нет метода, который бы создал его из `DataTable`, поэтому также придётся написать метод, который пройдёт по `DataSet` и для всех таблиц сделает маппинг объектов из типов `System.Data` в типы `Smo`.